# Javascript: Animate Div when it is in viewport

Tags: javascript, css

In the pictures you see 4 circles below the header,

I can not figure out how to make them animate as shown when they are in the viewport

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intersection_Observer_API to check for when the element is in viewport and apply the animations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```
function handleIntersectionEntry(entry) {
if (entry.length > 0) {
  const item = entry[0];
  const ratio = Math.floor(item.intersectionRatio);
  if (ratio > 0) {
    // ITEM IN VIEWPORT
  } else if (ratio < 1) {
   // ITEM OUT OF VIEWPORT
  }
}


  const config = {
    root: null,
    threshold: [1.0],
    rootMargin: "0px"
  };

  this.Observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    handleIntersectionEntry,
    config
  );

  this.Observer.observe('YOUR DOM ELEMENT TO MONITOR');
```

Polyfill for all browswer support: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill

Comment: Can you please provide a demo for the above

Comment: DEMO https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#A_simple_example

Comment: is there a simpler method to do this?

Comment: i just want it to be visible when it is viewed

Comment: I think this is the simplest method otherwise you need to put scroll listener on the document and poll the element you want to check and get its top left right bottom with respect to the viewport using getBoundingClientRect and find whether it is in viewport or not.

Comment: In handleIntersectionEntry in the if condition ratio > 0 put the code for the showing the item